# Do I Need to fund Stellar with Lumens for custom token based wallets too?

Tags: horizon

I want to create custom token for my system but it seems that I can not create a wallet unless I fund it with 1 XLM? Is it true? If not why my wallet is not being created?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true. There is a required [minimum XLM balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance) for any account and network fees are also paid in XLM for any (including custom asset payment) transaction.

You need at least 1 XLM plus 0.5 XLM for a trustline to your custom asset and I'd suggest at least another 0.1 XLM for transaction fees (altough it is possible to pay transaction fees from another account but that's another story) = 1.6 XLM

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I want to make it _free_? Do I need to create my own setup?

Comment: If free in terms of "I'll handle the fees on behalf of my users" see https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/channels.html . Otherwise you have to operate your own network (running your own stellar nodes with custom config).

Comment: I was talking about my own private network. What'd be in that case?

Comment: You have to run your own stellar-core and stellar-horizon servers. https://www.stellar.org/developers/software/